# pandas: process a column whose value is a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, pandas, filter, tuples

```
id   stage_seq
1    [(A,1), (B,3), (C,5)]
2    [(B,2), (C,2), (E,6)]
3    [(B,2), (C,1), (D,2), (E,3)]
```

I want to remove the records whose last stage is E and the second to last stage is D (i.e. remove record id = 3 in the above data frame). Here is my code:

```
df = df[(df.stage_seq[-1][0] != "E") | (df.stage_seq[-2][0] != "D")]
```

but I got the following error:

> df = df[(df.stage_seq[-1][0] != "E") | (df.stage_seq[-2][0] != "D")]
>
> KeyError: -1

What should be the correct way to process a pandas column whose value is a list?

Comment: Just for clarity, can you detangle this nested expression and indicate which of the subexpressions raises the exception? Also, please prepare a [mcve], it's required for your question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in one line without new columns, you can do the following:

```
df = df[df.stage_seq.apply(lambda x: x[-1][0] != 'E') | \
    df.stage_seq.apply(lambda x: x[-2][0] != 'D')]
```

The result is:

```
   id                 stage_seq
0   1  [(A, 1), (B, 3), (C, 5)]
1   2  [(B, 2), (C, 2), (E, 6)]
```

Your problem is that you are trying to access the lists within `df.stage_seq`, but the `df.column[x][y]` syntax doesn't do that.  Instead, you can use a lambda function to access the contents of each cell of `df.stage_seq`, and *then* select the list elements you want.  Note that this assumes all the cells in the real dataframe actually have values at these positions.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.str[]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) for select first tuples and then values in tuples, it working because `list` and `tuple` are iterables like `string`s:

```
df = df[(df.stage_seq.str[-1].str[0] != "E") | (df.stage_seq.str[-2].str[0] != "D")]
print (df)
   id                 stage_seq
0   1  [(A, 1), (B, 3), (C, 5)]
1   2  [(B, 2), (C, 2), (E, 6)]
```

**Details**:

```
print(df.stage_seq.str[-1])
0    (C, 5)
1    (E, 6)
2    (E, 3)
Name: stage_seq, dtype: object

print(df.stage_seq.str[-1].str[0])
0    C
1    E
2    E
Name: stage_seq, dtype: object
```

Alternative solution if no `NaN`s with `list comprehension` and values exist in positions:

```
df = df[[x[-1][0] != 'E' or x[-2][0] != 'D' for x in df.stage_seq]]
print (df)
   id                 stage_seq
0   1  [(A, 1), (B, 3), (C, 5)]
1   2  [(B, 2), (C, 2), (E, 6)]
```

First solution working too, if want select non exist tuples:

```
print(df.stage_seq.str[3])
0       NaN
1       NaN
2    (E, 3)
Name: stage_seq, dtype: object

print(df.stage_seq.str[3].str[0])
0    NaN
1    NaN
2      E
Name: stage_seq, dtype: object

print(df.stage_seq.str[3].str[0] == 'E')
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: stage_seq, dtype: bool
```

---

```
print ([x[3][0] != 'E' != 'D' for x in df.stage_seq])
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: the `str[]` method seems black magic. how did you discover it?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă - It is from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) - more general solution for select all iterables, not only `string`s. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

Create a new column which will contain only stages:

```
df['stage']  = df['stage_seq'].apply(lambda x: "".join(w for w,x in x))
```

Create two separate columns for last and 2nd last stage

```
df['last_stage'] = df['stage'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
df['2ndlast_stage'] = df['stage'].apply(lambda x: x[-2])
```

Filter the dataframe

```
df1=df[~((df['last_stage'] == 'E') & (df['2ndlast_stage'] == 'D'))]
```